# The definition of principal G-bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, definition, lie-groups, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles

I've encountered many different definitons of principal $G$ bundle from Morita's Geometry of differential forms , Hamilton's Mathematical gauge theory , Kobayashi and Nomizu's Foundations of differential geometry and wiki . (I'm crazy...)

But it seems that in different literature , they have such common properties (some are explaned as definitions, some are explaned as propositions, theorems or corollaries) .

Here is what I select : ( Suppose a fibre bundle is $(P,\pi,M,G)$)

> **Property 1** The action of $G$ on itself is left translation
>
> **Property 2** The action of $G$ on the total space $P$ to the right is free and smooth
>
> **Property 3** The quotient space have such identity : $P/G=M$
>
> **Property 4** The trivializing map satisfies $G-equavalent$ condition, whcih means :$\phi:\pi ^{-1}(U_\alpha)\cong U_\alpha\times G$ , then $$\phi(ug)=\phi(u)g $$ for $g\in G,u \in \pi ^{-1}(U_\alpha)$
>
> **Property 5** The action of $G$ preserves the fibres of $\pi$ and is simply transitive

It seems that if  you select some of it, then it becomes a new definition of principal $G$-bundle. I'm not sure whether these properties are equivalent or not.So can anyone else show me the connections with each definitions? Thanks for your advice!

Comment: "The action of $G$ on itself is left translation" is this relevant at all to a fibre bundle?

Comment: Property 4 is about equivariant bundles, not principal bundles. For instance, take any space $X$ and form the bundle $\pi \colon X \to X$. The trivial group acts on $X$, but this action is only free if $X$ is a single point.

Comment: @Joppy "A principal $G$-bundle is a fiber bundle with fiber $G$ and structure group $G$ where $G$ acts on itself by left translations".This is the definition found in Morita's Geometry of differential forms.

Comment: @Joppy Property 4 is found in  Kobayashi and Nomizu,also found in Hamilton.Some authors call it pricipal $G$ atlas(It seems that I should add subscrit $\alpha$).I guess property 3 is needless,because if you add the right action of $G$ on the previous fibre bundle,then $M$ naturally forms the quotient property by $P/G$.